# How to make selectable items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pug

Whenever I click on the button, I want the div to have added selected-class to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
template
          .d-flex.align-items-center.mt-2(
            :class="{ 'selected-class': itemSelected }",
        
          )
            p.mb-0.meal-plan Chicken Meal 
            b-button.breakfast-button.ml-auto(
              href="#",
              variant="primary",
              @click="chooseBreakfast(item)"
            ) Choose

data() {
    return {
      itemSelected: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    chooseBreakfast(item) {
      this.itemSelected = item;
    },
```

Comment: item is defined? at least not in your snipped

Answer (score 0):

If its one state (e.x when you select you cannot toggle it back), then just remove the item parameter and convert the method like that

```
chooseBreakfast() {
  this.itemSelected = true
}
```

If you need to have a toggle state remove again the item parameter and convert the method like that

```
chooseBreakfast() {
  this.itemSelected = !this.itemSelected
}
```

Also remove from the @click handler the item param in both cases